# What is the name for tests that uses Puppeteer or Selenium to test a website holistically?

Tags: automated-testing, terminology

In unit testing, individual units of source code get tested. But when you use Puppeteer or Selenium (both are headless browsers) you are doing black-box testing, in which you don't interact with the internal of a project.

What is the proper name for these types of tests? Typically a test would be  something like the following:

1. Open the login page
2. Find username and password edit boxes
3. Types the info
4. Find the submit button and press it
5. Assert that a welcome message is displayed

Does it only called **black-box testing** or **user interface testing** or there is a more proper name for it?

Comment: End to end tests or system tests.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're checking that a complete login flow - right from launching the browser to checking that the user successfully logs in- was performed, I would say these are `end to end` or `e2e` tests.